# Ruby on Rails - Wrong foreign key used in has_many through join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Rails 5.2, Postgres 10.4

New to rails. I have a has_many :through relationship that I'm trying to join on, however, Rails seems to be using the wrong foreign key despite my definition.

A user will enrol in many opportunities through opportunity enrolment. An opportunity could have many users enrol.

**opportunity.rb**

```
class Opportunity < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :opportunity_enrolment, :class_name => 'OpportunityEnrolment', :foreign_key => "opportunity_id"
  has_many :volunteers, through: :opportunity_enrolment, :foreign_key => "opportunity_id"
end
```

**opportunity_enrolment.rb**

```
class OpportunityEnrolment < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :opportunities, foreign_key: "id"
  has_many :volunteers, foreign_key: "id"
end
```

**users.rb**

```
class Volunteer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :opportunity_enrolment, :class_name => 'OpportunityEnrolment', foreign_key: "volunteer_id"
  has_many :opportunities, through: :opportunity_enrolment, foreign_key: "opportunity_id"
end
```

When showing a specific user and then joining that user to their opportunities, I get the very first record in the opportunities table as the join is created incorrectly.

```
<% @volunteer.opportunities.each do |volunteerenrolment| %>
  <table frame="box">
    <tr><td>Name: <%= volunteerenrolment.oppname %></td></tr> --Oppname is in the opportunities table.
    <tr><td>Created: <%= volunteerenrolment.created_at %></td></tr>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

Rails creates the following select statement.

```
SELECT "opportunities".* FROM "opportunities" INNER JOIN "opportunity_enrolments" ON "opportunities"."id" = "opportunity_enrolments"."id" WHERE "opportunity_enrolments"."volunteer_id" = $1
```

opportunity_enrolments.id is the primary key on the opportunity_enrolments table. I need my app to join on opportunity_enrolments.opportunity_id instead, like so:

```
SELECT "opportunities".* FROM "opportunities" INNER JOIN "opportunity_enrolments" ON "opportunities"."id" = "opportunity_enrolments"."opportunity_id" WHERE "opportunity_enrolments"."volunteer_id" = $1
```

For the life of me I don't know where Rails is pulling the incorrect foreign key from. I've tried to change it in my model multiple times, but Rails doesn't seem to look there. If I manually write the correct select statement using a .joins, then everything works perfect, but I want to keep in line with the "convention over configuration"

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you think it should be `has_many :opportunity_enrolments` (plural)?

Comment: what does your schema look like for the three tables?

Comment: @nathan I think `OpportunityEnrolment ` this is join table but you have setup wrong association in this. Please go through below link. May be you can solve it on your own then.
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: Got the answer for this one. I was inconsistent in my singular/plural references in the model. The opportunity_enrolment relationship on users was just one of them. Also had an issue on the OpportunityEnrolment model as well. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `OpportunityEnrollment` table is the glue between your `Opportunity` and `Volunteer` classses and should really be using a `belongs_to`.  Plus, you can use the rails defaults which will interpret the class names and foreign keys for you.

Also don't define a class called 'Volunteer' in  file called 'users.rb'

opportunity.rb

```
class Opportunity < ApplicationRecord
  # note the plural below as per rails convention
  has_many :opportunity_enrolments
  has_many :volunteers, through: :opportunity_enrolments
end
```

opportunity_enrolment.rb

```
class OpportunityEnrolment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :opportunity
  belongs_to :volunteer 
end
```

volunteer.rb

```
class Volunteer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :opportunity_enrolments
  has_many :opportunities, through: :opportunity_enrolments
end
```

Your join table should have `opportunity_id` and `volunteer_id` fields.

Comment: That worked! I think I over-thought my relationships, then started playing around singular/plural in the models and got in a spaghetti mess. Thanks for your help!